# UDF DVD mount issues in Maverick

Tags: 10.10, mount, permissions, udf

When I insert the DVD into my drive i see it mounts, but i can not access it unless i am root.
Doing `ls -l` on the mount i get no access permissions:

> $ `pwd`
> /media
>
> $ `ls -l`
> d--------- 4 haimov haimov 136 2011-05-06 05:22 UDF Volume

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the file `/etc/fstab` on the line concerning the DVD/CD drive, in the forth space separated column, does it have the word 'user' or 'users'?  This may be part of a comma separated list.  Mine says:

```
/dev/scd0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0
```

Also, are you logged in as a NON-root user at the GUI, before putting the disc in?

Note: 'user' and 'users' have some important differences, 'user', singular, is the one you want if you have any doubts.

Comment: Why do you have your DVD Drive in fstab?